# Find the playlists a video is in via Youtube API

Tags: api, youtube, playlist

I want to know which playlists contain a certain video. The opposite is easy: find which video's are in a playlist, but I don't want that.

I can already have YT do this via the following route, but that's stupid and slow:

- get channelId from video data (`videos?id=...`)
- get playlists from channelId (`playlists?channelId=...`)
- loop through all playlists and find all their videos (`playlistItems?playlistId=...`)

Like I said: stupid and slow. These steps are possible, because I only want playlists authored by the video's author. (Otherwise I'd have to download all of YT.)

What I'm looking for, sort of, is a request: `playlists?videoId=...`, but of course that doesn't exist.

Is there a better way than my 3 steps?

PS. I've created [the script to use my 3 steps](http://public.home.hotblocks.nl/yt.js), but it's A LOT of requests. That and the playlists don't seem to have usable playlist ID's... I need the ID that the browser uses to show the playlist GUI style.

Comment: Because a video can occur in many playlists, I don't think this is possible. If it's possible you still would have to define a set of playlists to search in. I took a look in the YT API and couldn't find anything similar to your request.

Comment: I'm only interested in the author's playlists, so that should limit it, but I think you're right. YT's API should have this =(

Comment: Can you talk about what you want to achieve? "I need the ID that the browser uses to show the playlist GUI style." While I don't think YouTube provides such an API, maybe there is a workaround to your end goal.

Comment: This is so helpful for my app that finds related songs crowd sourced. A music service like Pandora that finds similar songs by analyzing all the playlists this song is in and playing commonly (and hopefully) similar music.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the Youtube API does not support a call like this, and in my opinion never will. This is probably an intentional decision by Youtube to hide the playlists, even the YT Analytics API doesn't show how many lists use your video.

It seems the way you do it is the only workaround - in case you only need the playlists for one specific user.

Comment: The way I did it doesn't work anymore =) Some API or JS change, I don't know. Strange intention IMO. Google is all about the analytics!